# Material design md-tabs with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I have a question regarding material design md-tabs control. I am using md-tabs with Angularjs on one of the pages and it works fine. I also have a md-button on that page and what we want to do is, when user click that button we want to move to the next tab. I am new to this whole material-angular thing and would appreciate if somebody could guide me in right direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `md-selected` attribute on `md-tabs` directive. `md-tabs` uses `md-selected` attribute to decide which tab is selected. So you can simply update `$scope.selectedTab` on click of your `md-button` to select the desired tab.

Have a look at this code snippet:

```js
angular.module("material", ["ngMaterial", "ngAnimate"])

.controller("tabCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.selectedTab = 0;
    
    $scope.changeTab = function() {
        if ($scope.selectedTab === 2) {
            $scope.selectedTab = 0;
        }
        else {
            $scope.selectedTab++;
        }
        
    }
}]);
```

```css
.tab-content {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    text-align:center;
}

.tab-container {
    height:120px;
}

.tab-change-row {
    text-align:center;
}

.tab-change-btn {
    display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="material">
    <div ng-controller="tabCtrl">
        <div class="tab-container">
            <md-tabs md-selected="selectedTab">
                <md-tab label="One">
                    <p class="tab-content">Tab One content</p>
                </md-tab>
                <md-tab label="Two">
                    <p class="tab-content">Tab Two content</p>
                </md-tab>
                <md-tab label="Three">
                    <p class="tab-content">Tab Three content</p>
                </md-tab>
            </md-tabs>      
        </div>
       
        
        <div class="tab-change-row">
            <md-button class="tab-btn md-raised" ng-click="changeTab()">Change Tab</md-button>    
        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Brilliant, great answer!

Answer (score 0):

we can use "`selectedIndex`"  for doing this, put the tab index value as selectedindex then it will make that tab active, we can use selectedIndex in `<md-tab-group>` it  will start from zero.
For more details please review [tabs](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/tabs/README.md)